# characteristic of a finite field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

knowing that the characteristic of an integral domain is $0$ or a prime number, i want to prove that the characteristic of a finite field $F_n$ is a prime number, that is $\operatorname{char}(F_n)\not = 0$. the proof i'm reading uses the fact that within $e,2e,3e,\ldots$ there are two that are necessarily equal $ie=(i+k)e$ so $ke=0$ for some positive $k$. But can i say the following argument:
$F_n=\{0,e,x_1,\ldots ,x_{n-2}\}$ ( $e$ is the multiplicative identity ) and since $e\not = 0$ then $e\not = 2e\not =\cdots ,\not = ne$ so we have $n$ distinct elements $ie, i=1,\ldots,n$ of $F_n$ hence one of them must equal $0$; $ie=0$ for some $i\in \{2,\ldots,n\}$, moreover the trivial  field with one element $e=0$ has obviously characteristic $1$. Is there a non-trivial field where $e=0$?

Comment: What is your definition of characteristic?

Comment: if $e+e=e$ does'nt this imply that $e=0$?

Comment: On what grounds do you assert that $e\neq 2e\neq\cdots,\neq ne$"? It's not even true in general: in the field of 4 elements, you do **not** have any element $e$ with $e,2e,3e,4e$ pairwise distinct.

Comment: @palio: certainly not! It implies that $(1+1)e=0$, so either $e=0$ **or** $1+1=0$; i.e., the characteristic could be $2$.

Comment: You might want to try considering the prime factorization of the integer $k$ because you need to find a prime $p$ for which $pe=0$ (if $k$ factors as $k=mn$, what can you say about the elements $me$ and $ne$?).

Comment: you are using substraction in a case and not in the other: since $e+e=e$ then $e+e+e=e+e=e$ then by substracting $-e$ you get $e+e+e-e=e-e=0$ hence $e+e=0$ but why didn't you substruct $-e$ from the beginning i mean since $e+e=e$ then $e+e-e=e-e=0$ so $e=0$ ?

Comment: @palio $e+e=e$ is not possible (except in the zero ring), and it does imply that $e=0$. But what happens in characteristic two is $e+e+e=e$ (and consequently $e+e=0$).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin : here $ne$ i not a real multiplication, it is only a formal way to write $e+e+...+e$;  $n$ times. so saying that $1+1=0$ has no meaning to me

Comment: @palio: I misread what you wrote; from $e+e=e$ you *can* conclude $e=0$; but what if $e\neq 2e$, $2e\neq 3e$, but $e=3e$? Then you have $e=e+e+e$, from which you get $0=e+e$. Note in particular that just because $e\neq 2e$, and $2e\neq 3e$, this does *not* tell you that $e\neq 3e$. Inequality is not transitive.

Comment: @palio: I **know** it's not real multiplication. But every field has an element which is the multiplicative identity, and that is usually called $1$. So $1+1$ *does* make sense: it means the multiplicative identity added to itself. And for every element $e$ in the field, you have $e+e = 1e+1e = (1+1)e$ by distributivity. You never said what $e$ was, I assumed it was merely some element in the field. If you meant it to be the multiplicative identity, you needed to say so.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin : i'm sorry arturo i thaught it was clear from my notation of $F_n=\{0,e,x_1,...,x_{n-2}\}$ but yes by $e$, I meant the multiplicative identity of $F_n$. But the example you gave of $e\not = 3e$ explains it all. thank you !!

Comment: There is no "trivial field with one element". The definition of a field includes the statement that the multiplicative identity is not the additive identity.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: There are many results, papers, conferences about the field with one element introduced first by Tits.

Answer (score 20):

Let $1$ denote the *multiplicative* identity of the field.  Then, $1 \neq 0$ where $0$ is the *additive* identity.  So every field must have at least two elements: your notion of a field with one element $0$ is not correct.

So, since the field contains $1$, it contains $1+1$, $1+1+1$, $1 + 1 + 1 + 1, \ldots, 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1$ (where the last sum has $n$ $1$s in it).  All these $n$ sums cannot be distinct since the field has only $n-1$ *nonzero* elements.  So,
for some distinct $i$ and $j$, the sum of $i$ $1$s must equal the sum of $j$ $1$s,
and by subtraction, the sum of $|i-j|$ $1$s must equal $0$.  The smallest number of $1$s that sum to $0$ is called the characteristic of the finite field, and the characteristic  must be a prime number.  This is because if the 
characteristic were a composite
number $ab$, then the sum of $a$ $1$s multiplied by the sum of $b$ $1$s, 
which equals the sum of $ab$ $1$s by the distributive law, would equal
$0$, that is, the product of two nonzero elements would equal $0$,
which cannot happen in a field.

Answer (score 5):

I feel as though the answer you are stating is making things more difficult. As you pointed out all integral domains are either characterstic zero or of prime characteristic, and so in particular all fields are of prime characteristic or zero characteristic. But, if a field has characteristic zero you know that it's multiplicative identity has infinite additive order and all finite groups (and thus all finite fields) have no elements of infinite order (for the reason FIRST reason you stated).  Another route is, if you know group theory (but this is really overkill compared to the other two arguments) to note that $|\mathbb{F}_q|\mathbb{F}_q=0$ by Lagrange's theorem, and so all elements have order dividing $|\mathbb{F}_q|$.

To answer your last question, no, there are no non-trivial examples where $1=0$ since the ONLY ring with such an identity is the zero ring.