# To every finite field K there exists a positive integer m sucht that m*a = a + a + ... + a ( a times ) = 0 for every a in K

Tags: linear-algebra

How can i prove this:

1.
To every finite field K there exists a positive integer m sucht that 
m*a = a + a + ... + a ( a times ) = 0 for every a in K.

2. The smallest positive integer m > 0 in 1. is a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in a finite field $(F,+,.)$ ,$(F,+)$ is a finite group with zero element $0_F$.

In a finite group every element has finite order .Hence for each $a\in F$ there exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $n.a=0$

Answer (score 0):

Every field contains $1$ and $0$ by definition. The [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) of a finite field must be a prime number, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77623/characteristic-of-a-finite-field). Then $1+1\cdots +1=0, i.e., p\cdot 1=0$. Hence $p\cdot a=0$.